# Не могу взять данные из mongodb и вывести их на сайт

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Код скрипта в файле index.html(файл находится в папке public):

```
`// Получение всех пользователей
    async function getTelegrams() {
const response = await fetch("/api/telegrams", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
});
        
        // если запрос прошел нормально
        if (response.ok === true) {
            // получаем данные
            const telegrams = await response.json();
            let rows = document.querySelector("#statusTable tbody");
            telegrams.forEach((telegrams) => {
                // добавляем полученные элементы в таблицу
                rows.append(row(telegrams));
            });
        }
    }
    
    // Создание строки для таблицы
    function row(telegrams) {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");
        const nameTd = document.createElement("td");
        nameTd.append(telegrams.name);
        tr.append(nameTd);
        return tr;
    }
    
    // Вызываем функцию для получения пользователей при загрузке страницы
    getTelegrams();
    `
```

Код файла server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const app = express();
const jsonParser = express.json();

const mongoClient = new MongoClient("ссылка на облачное mongodb");

(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoClient.connect();
    app.locals.collection = mongoClient.db("Hopeless").collection("telegrams");
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Сервер ожидает подключения...");
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
})();

app.get("/api/telegrams", async (req, res) => {
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
  try {
    const telegrams = await collection.find({}).project({ name: 1 }).toArray();
    res.send(telegrams);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

process.on("SIGINT", async () => {
  await mongoClient.close();
  console.log("Приложение завершило работу");
  process.exit();
});
```

Как выглядит ошибка(в консоли браузера):

`GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)`

Лично мне кажется что я где-то ошибся с путями. База называется Hopeless, а внутри нее таблица(ну или отсек для данных я не знаю в общем) telegrams, там есть у каждой записи name, мне его и нужно вывести!